# Bleed space for creative

Tags: bleed

I am making a New Year Standee and would like to know what the bleed space should be. I am making the creative in Illustrator. Kindly help

Comment: Ask your printer what bleed is required.

Comment: "Ask your printer" is always the right answer. Not having the information from from the printer makes me wonder what else you haven't discussed -- screen frequency, total ink limit, font handling, recommended trapping, proof and press check arrangements, etc., etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb always design with .125" (1/8") bleed. This is the most common standard for printers. Occasionally I'll get files with .0625" (1/16") of bleed but that's pretty uncommon.

1/8" is used so widely because it allows for a good amount of space for production to use without worrying about really thin margins for error.